# How can I install Wine software in Ubuntu 17.04?

Tags: wine

I have found wine software in Ubuntu software Software, but the rating is low. Is it good or is there any source or command to install wine?

Answer (score 0):

It works. WineHQ recommend doing installs their way.

https://wiki.winehq.org/Ubuntu

Comment: This is a link only answer and is not better than the existing answer. We use mark and close questions as duplicates in an attempt to maintain one high quality answer to common questions rather than hundreds of low quality answers. Just keep this in mind as you gain reputation. Until then you can add a comment "Possible duplicate - link"

Answer (score 0):

Wine software is more trouble than it's worth. It's very finicky, and requires a lot of manual tweaking to get many software apps to run.

If you're interested in running Windows apps on Ubuntu, a much more reliable and pleasant experience can be had by installing Virtualbox, and then installing a real Windows guest OS into Virtualbox. See https://www.virtualbox.org/ for more information about Virtualbox.

Comment: I agree 100 % with your advice, however, it is not really an answer as the OP wishes to install wine. Wine works well with simple programs

Comment: @Panther The OP asks the question "Is it (Wine) good"? My answer directly addresses that question :-)

Comment: OK, thanks for the answer. I am NOT downvoting (FWIW), just commenting.